# Finding if a sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\sqrt{k} \\ b_n=a_n + a_{n+1} \\\text{Show the sequence }(b_n)_{n=1}^\infty \text{ converges and determine the limit} \lim_{n\to\infty}b_n $$

So obviously I can start the question as follows:
$$ b_n = \sum_{k=1}^na_n + \sum_{k=1}^na_{n+1} \\ = \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k\sqrt{k} + \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^k\sqrt{k}$$

Can anyone given any hints on where to go next?

Comment: Note through algebraic manipulation: $\sqrt{k+1} - \sqrt{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1} + \sqrt{k}}$